# Communication from child component to parent with Stencil.js

Tags: javascript, stenciljs

What is the best method to send data from a child component to the parent in Stencil.js?

I tried using a callback method, but it looks like it is imperative to use Events to accomplish this. It seems to me that we write a lot more to have 2 way data transfer than I would think it is necessary.
I have to mention that I am building a web components library that could be used later in either React or Angular projects.

Comment: Stencil is a framework for building _web components_, and another name for web components is _custom HTML elements_. As such, a _web component_ is something very different from a React-/Angular-Component, despite the similar name. HTML elements _do not know the concept of a "parent" component_ in the React/Angular/Vue/etc sense. You question is as if you'd ask "how to communicate from an `<li>` to a `<ul>`?".

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. Your post needs improvement.

Comment: If you're building components to  be used in a data-driven framework, use that framework for data and event handling. Don't expect your component to do it in isolation.

Comment: Thanks for the responses; it seems I didn't read the stencil.js docs enough and I understand what was my mistake.
My main issue is that these HTML elements will not be used by a single framework - I guess Events and Watchers is the only solution in this case.

Answer (score 0):

The recommended ways to communicate with a parent component is indeed through a custom event. But there are some other options as well, which might make more sense in some situations:

**Direct upward communication** 
You can manually select a parent component and set attributes or properties on it:

```
this.el.closest('my-parent').myProp = 123;
```

**[Stencil Store](https://github.com/ionic-team/stencil-store)** 
A state library by the Stencil team to communicate with a central store, which other components can watch for changes. Note that I never tried it with Angular or React, but I think it should still work.

Answer (score 0):

If your are writing both parent and child components using JSX, standard data binding can work (if that's what you mean by "send data"), as long as you bind objects not simple strings, numbers, or booleans.

Suppose you have a parent component that renders a child component including a property of type object:

```
export class Parent {

anObject;

render() {
    return(
        <child myObject={this.anObject}></child>
    );
}
```

Any changes that the child makes to its `myObject` will be reflected back to the parent's `anObject`.

If you are just using DOM, then, of course, this won't work.